# Правильно: на языке / на языках?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильнее?

> Анкеты были составлены как на русском, так и на английском языке.

или

> Анкеты были составлены как на русском, так и на английском языках.

Answer (score 3):

В вашей фразе правильным будет первый вариант:

> Анкеты были составлены как на русском, так и на английском язык**е**.

Второй же ваш вариант тоже возможен, но без составного союза "как... так и":

> Анкеты были составлены на русском и английском язык**ах**.

В первом случае число единственное, потому что языки в таком выражении рассматриваются по отдельности, и после "как на русском" слово "языке" опущено, но подразумевается.

---

Вот пара ответов Грамоты, где говорится про число существительного:

**Вопрос № 292905**

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно: "Изменяется как большую, так и в меньшую сторонУ" или "Изменяется как большую, так и в меньшую сторонЫ". Почему?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Имя существительное, которому предшествует два или несколько определений, ставится в форме единственного числа, если между определениями стоят противительные, разделительные или сопоставительные союзы. Союз **как... так и** сопоставительный, поэтому верно: *Изменяется как большую, так и в меньшую сторону.*

---

**Вопрос № 283118**

Добрый день! Уважаемая поддержка, объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно и почему:
...как на платной, так и на бесплатной основе(ах)...

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

При союзе **как... так и...** имя существительное, которому предшествует два определения, принимает форму единственного числа: *как на платной, так и на бесплатной основе.*

Comment: Не вижу принципиальной разницы между конструкциями "Она знает русский и английский языки" и "Она знает как русский так и английский языки". Вот пример из статьи:
"Законы, в той или иной мере ущемляющие права и свободы личности, издаются как на федеральном, так и региональном уровнях [«Адвокат» (2004)]" http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы#321

Comment: На мой взгляд, для иллюстрации употребления союза "как... так и" в этом источнике использован _неудачный_ пример из журналистики. Вопрос же единственного или множественного числа в том параграфе не разбирается как таковой. Множественое число при этом союзе и однородных подлежащих возникает у _сказуемого_ (Как английский, так и русский язык _были использованы_ при составлении той анкеты) - об этом есть у Розенталя. http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliii-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-podlezhashchim/ss-190-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-odnorodnymi-podlezhashchimi

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, за такое верное наблюдение (что вопрос числа не разбирается)! И про множественное всё правильно, полезно тем, кто не знает этого.

Comment: Спасибо. А что насчет такого: "Анкеты были составлены и на русском, и на английском языках.". Здесь уже соединительный союз и..и... Значит фраза корректна?? А отсюда уже не далеко и до  "Анкеты были составлены и как на русском, и также на английском языках.". Ну вы понимаете, что границы между сопоставительными и соединительными союзами эфемерны..

Comment: С "и... и" то же, что и с "как... так и" — единственное число. А конструкции "и как... и также" нету! К "как... так и" и то нельзя в начале И добавить.